# Shading a frame title in PaloAlto beamer

Tags: beamer, shading, frame-title

I'm not an expert in beamer and after a few hours on the web not finding how to do exactly what I want I'm asking for help.

I would like to create a beamer using PaloAlto theme with a few customization.

First of all, I'd like to shade de frame title background from my color (in the logo corner) to white (to the right). I've found a few guys who wanted something similar and tried the solutions they were given but nothing seems to do the trick for me.

Secondly, I'd like to do the same with the vertical sidebar (from the logo corner) to white (the bottom).

Finally, I also want the title background not to appear on the title page and the title block to move up a bit.

Thanks ahead for your help !

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme[sidebar]{PaloAlto}

%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\newcommand{\degrade}[1]{\color{msl!80}#1\xspace}

\definecolor{msl}{RGB}{27,145,165}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

%\logo{\includegraphics[scale = 0.05]{logo-dUCKS.jpg} \hspace{-200pt}}

%\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.



%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.

%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}


\usecolortheme[RGB={27,145,165}]{structure}

%\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=2cm}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=msl!20!msl}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=msl}
%\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=msl} 
\setbeamercolor{title in sidebar}{fg=white}



\makeatletter
\setlength\beamer@sidebarwidth{2cm}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]


%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line

%\setbeamersize{sidebar left width=2.5cm}

%}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Question]{How to shade in PaloAlto} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Buzz} % Your name
\institute[TEST] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
TEST \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{buzz.lightning@free.fr} % Your email address
}
\date{29 mars 2016} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide



\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
\section{TEST 1} % Sections can be created in order to organize your presentation into discrete blocks, all sections and subsections are automatically printed in the table of contents as an overview of the talk
%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

\begin{itemize}

\item Test 1

\item Test 10
~
\item Test 100
~
\item Test 1000


\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Test 2}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test 2
~
\item Test 20
~
\item Test 200
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%-----------------------------------------------

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{frame}
\Huge{\centerline{Conclusion}}
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at this template. It seems to check the page/slide number to see if the slide is title slide or not and apply the background accordingly. line number 48  https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports/src/62840a66640d6b38da8618a71c591b1ea769a345/beamerthemeMedian.sty?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: A few other comments: You do not need `\usepackage{xcolor}`, beamer does this for you, same for `\usepackage{graphicx} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puh, so many question in a single question!

1) To shade the title I had to redefine the headline and replace the `\rule`, which normally supplies the background colour by an horizontal shading

2) shading the sidebar was a bit easier, I had just to replace the `sidebar canvas left` template by a vertical shading

3) Is the frame option `plain` sufficient for your?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{msl}{RGB}{27,145,165}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\usecolortheme[RGB={27,145,165}]{structure}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=2cm}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=msl!20!msl}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=msl}
\setbeamercolor{title in sidebar}{fg=white}

\makeatletter
\setlength\beamer@sidebarwidth{2cm}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

\title{How to shade in PaloAlto} 
\author{Buzz} 
\institute{TEST}
\date{29 mars 2016} 

\colorlet{titleright}{white}
\colorlet{titlemid}{msl}
\colorlet{titleleft}{msl}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
    color(\beamer@sidebarwidth)=(titlemid);%
    color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)%
}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@sidebar}{\beamer@sidebarwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(titleright);%
    color(\sidebarheight)=(titleleft)%
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}%
        \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
        \else%
        \hfill%
        \fi%
        \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@headheight}%
            \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}%
            \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@headheight}}%
            \pgfusepath{clip}%
            \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}%
        \end{pgfpicture}%
        \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
            \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
        \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
        \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{%
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@sidebar}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hspace*{-1.5cm}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC} 
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]